# Simulate a request inside a controller

Tags: symfony

I'm working in a symfony project and i have two function in my controller :

```
function1Action ($request Request, $product) {
    $quantity = $request->request->get('quantity')
    //dothingshere
}
function2Action($product, $value) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $pattern = $em->getRepository('repo')->find($value)
    //return an array ['quantity'=>x]
    $this->function1Action($pattern, $product)
}
```

usually the user call the function 1 (post request) with the good request parameter. So here all is good. My problem is sometimes, the function 2 is gonna be call and when it is i need to call function 1 but i don't have a proper Request and i want to send `$pattern`

So i found 3 solution

Solution 1 : 
create function1bis who does the same thing as function1 but take an array as parameter

Solution 2 : Initiate a null value in my first function

```
function1 ($request Request, $product, $patt=null) {
    if(!$patt){
        $quantity = $request->request->get('quantity')
    }
    else {
        $quantity = $patt['quantity']
    }
    //dothingshere
}
function2($product, $value) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $pattern = $em->getRepository('repo')->find($value)
    //return an array ['quantity'=>x]
    $this->function1Action(null, $product, $pattern);
}
```

Solution 3 : 
create an object Request inside function2.

I was trying to do solution 3 but i can't find how and i'm wondering wish one is 'the best'and if the solution 3 is not bad programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did the option 1. Seems more logical and with that it can be used at other moment. Solution 2 seemed to be risky due to the null parameter who could have caused problem somewhere else and Solution 3 would have take much more ressources since i have to do a foreach inside my function2. So my solution looks like that :

```
function1Action ($request Request, $product) {
    $quantity = $request->request->get('quantity')
    //dothingshere
}
function1bis($pattern, $product) {
    $quantity = $pattern['quantity']
    //dothingshere
}

function2Action($product, $value) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $pattern = $em->getRepository('repo')->find($value)
    //return an array ['quantity'=>x]
    $this->function1bis($pattern, $product)
}
```